# pgfplots: shift the xlabel in the middle of the diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

What do I have to set, to get the xlabel exactly in the middle of the diagram?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={This is the x-label},
xlabel style={fill=yellow,
at={([shift={(xticklabel* cs:0.5)}]yticklabel* cs:0.5)},
},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `xlabel style` (correctly) define position of label:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={This is the x-label},
xlabel style={fill=yellow,
               at={(0.5,0.5)}, anchor=center}, % <---
]
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]